# htaccess conditional access for domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a server setup that uses domain mapping, so many sites are sitting in the same `/public_html/`. One of the domains, **example.com** has an app dedicated exclusively for it, located in: `/public_html/foobar/`. How do I write an .htaccess condition that 404’s other domains from accessing this folder.

In pseudo, I'm basically looking for:

`if the request is “/foobar/“
    if the domain isn’t requested from “example.com”
        send 404`

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)*example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^foobar/  - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and quick response. However I'm looking for if the domain **isn't** `example.com` to 404 the `/foobar/` request, i.e.:
 
`other_site1.com/foobar/ = 404`, `anothersite.com/foobar/ = 404`, `example.com/foobar/ = 200`  theres dozens of sites, so was looking for a != statement of some sorts.

Comment: oh figured it out, just needed a `!` infront of `^(www\.)*example\.com` thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly. I lost it when wrote. Glad to help